# Capistrano 3: parametrized roles

Tags: capistrano

I'm creating a simple deploy script that is going to do some tasks in different servers defined in roles:

```
set :branch, ENV["PROJECT_GIT_BRANCH"]
role :app_servers, %w{app@server1.example.com app@server2.example.com}
role :main_server, %w{app@server1.example.com}
```

I can parametrize easily the "branch", but not the roles. Or I don't understant how to do that.

How can I parametrize the strings like "app@server1.example.com" using command line params or environment variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself ;)

```
role :app_servers, ENV['app_servers'].split(',')
role :main_server, ENV['app_servers'].split(',')[0]
```

So now I can do:

```
cap production deploy branch=master app_servers=app@server1.example.com,app@server2.example.com
```